# Why is this Countifs function not working?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, array-formulas

Can someone please tell me why this formula is not working?

=Sum(Countifs($B$8:$B$26,{"Sgt";"Cpl";"Gnr";"2*"},$D$8:$D$26,72,$D$6,{"MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI"}))

From all the testing I've done it seems to be the range of cells. I've checked online already and from everything I've read it should work!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`COUNTIFS` requires the range to be of the same dimension. `$B$8:$B$26` and `$D$8:$D$26` is 19 rows across, but `$D$6` is a single cell. So counting cannot be done.